# Using a Batch-Script to add a date between the filename and the extension of it

Tags: date, variables, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have a Script that is searching for the newest file in the directory "test" and gives it the variable "Newest".

```
pushd c:\Test
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set Newest=%%I
```

Now let's assume that the name of the file is `ThisFile.txt`.
I now want to rename it to `ThisFile_yyyymmdd.txt` by using my variable `%Newest%`.

What I have so far is this:

```
Set TDate=%date:~6,6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
ren %Newest% "%Newest%%TDATE%"
```

This however renames my file to `ThisFile.txt_yyyymmdd` which obviously removes the extension and ruins the file.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Keep in mind that I *have to* rename it by using the variable `%Newest%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go . Also `%%i` are case sensitive.

```vb
@echo off
setlocal

pushd c:\Test
Set "TDate=%date:~6,6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%"
for /f %%I in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do (
    echo ren %%~fI "%%~nI_%TDATE%%%~xI"
)
exit /b 0
```

Must read `FOR/?`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Do you mind explaining what exactly this code does? Just for better understanding.

Comment: @HonigdaxGuides It's your code, I only added `echo` command in front of `rename` command. Fixed the case sensitive loop variable and changed useless variable to `%%~fI`. Just try, is not destructive batch. Remove the `echo` in front of rename command if you want to apply change.

Comment: Hey, I already tried it and it works exactly how I want it to work :) I was just wondering what the "%%~nI_%TDATE%%%~xI" exactly does. Does %%~n simply mean everything before the "." (dot) and %%~x means everything after the "."  ?

Comment: @HonigdaxGuides open the cmd and  type `FOR /?` then press any key to the see next pages until you see the text about `%%~fI` :)

Comment: Ahh, perfect :) Thanks a lot. Got the perfect understanding of it now ^^

Comment: @HonigdaxGuides Also just to add you can get help of any command if you type `/?` after the command, eg. `echo /?` `setlocal /?` `exit /?` etc Edit, the site list resource reading for batch here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting